# Using URL Rewrite to remove folder from url redirect

Tags: regex, url, iis, url-rewriting

Consider a structure as follow:

```
/folderx/a.aspx
/folderx/b.aspx
/foldery/c.aspx
/folderz/d.aspx
```

Currently **browser shows/displays** the following URLs »

```
https://xxx.domain.yyy/folderx/a.aspx
https://xxx.domain.yyy/folderx/b.aspx
https://xxx.domain.yyy/foldery/c.aspx
https://xxx.domain.yyy/folderz/d.aspx
```

How can we **redirect** to **show/display** the following URLs **in browser** address bar instead? »

```
https://xxx.domain.yyy/a
https://xxx.domain.yyy/b
https://xxx.domain.yyy/c
https://xxx.domain.yyy/d
```

Condition:

- No hardcoding of `folderx`, `foldery`, `folderz`, etc. in URLs match

Trying to get this for days now, but unable to arrive at working set of rules that satisfy the above.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.aspx$ http%3://%1/$2 [NC,R=301,QSA,L,CO=dir:$1:%1:0:/]
```

First rule will [redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) request `domain/directory/file.aspx` to `domain/file` and [set cookie](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) `dir` with path information from the original request.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;\s*)dir=([^;]+)
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1.aspx [QSA,L]
```

Second rule will [read cookie](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) `dir` and serve the request based on the path of the original request. This will lead to removing directory from url with proper routing...

Answer (score 0):

Without hard coding possible folder names, this is impossible. How would mod_rewrite magically know which folders are possible? It has to be hard-coded. It violates your condition, but it's the only way.

It can try each one, so it doesn't have to know which folders match up with which aspx files, but it does have to know which folders are possible. If you know which folders are possible (say, "folderx", "foldery", and "folderz"), you can do it with a series of rewrites for each possible folder, like so:

```
RewriteCond /folderx%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /folderx/$1.aspx [L,QSA]

RewriteCond /foldery%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /foldery/$1.aspx [L,QSA]

RewriteCond /folderz%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.aspx -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /folderz/$1.aspx [L,QSA]
```

These rules say "if a file exists with the aspx extension in the defined folder, rewrite to it".

Comment: Folder/directory is included in the original request. I believe OP wants such request to be redirected to url without folder/directory listed in the url, but to keep proper routing into folder/directory from the original request.

Comment: @Ωmega, possibly, but I didn't interpret to mean a literal redirect. I interpreted it to mean the second form should be able to rewrite to the first without actually having to go to the first first and be redirected -- making your cookie solution not really work (cookie never set if they never visit the original url). But maybe I interpreted wrong.

Comment: @Ωmega, nonetheless, I gave you a +1 on your answer because your solution will work if the OP is okay with requiring the user to visit the original form first and redirecting.

Comment: I believe OP wants long url to be changed to short one, entering long one. I think his/her concern is that browser will show/display short url in address bar. So the actual url that browser gets is the long one...

Comment: @Ωmega -- as I said, I interpreted differently (i.e. shorturl might be directly accessed). But I understand your interpretation and agree that your solution will work if that's the case.